# Find concrete class using a dynamic expression (where a Class instance is passed to a DAO)

Tags: java, hibernate

I have this method signature:

```
public int nrOfEntities(Class<? extends MailConfirmation> clazz, User user, String email)
```

I would like nrOfEntities to return the number of entities that:

- Are of the concrete class clazz
- Have a matching User if user != null
- Have a matching email if user == null

It's the class matching I'm having a problem with. I've tried a few statements without any luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can clazz have subtypes that should not be counted?

If not, is it not sufficient to create the query on clazz?

```
Criteria criteria = session.createCriteria(clazz);
if (user == null) {
    criteria.add(Restrictions.eq("email", email);
} else {
    criteria.add(Restrictions.eq("user", user);
}
int result = (Integer) criteria.setProjection(Projections.rowCount()).uniqueResult();
```

Now I am guessing how your mapping looks (that there are "email" and "user" properties).

If that is not working, I know that there is a pseudo property named "class", at least in HQL. Maybe you can experiment with that.

Comment: Ah, excellent. I spent 5 minutes looking for the pseudo property but couldn't find it. Using the Criteria API was new ground for me, worked great though. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to test the class of an object, you should be able to use something like the following:

```
Object entity = ... // Get the entity however
boolean matchesClass = entity.getClass().equals(clazz);
```

If this isn't working for you, give some examples of how it fails since it should be this straightforward!

Comment: Of course that would match. But I want to fetch Hibernate entities of the class clazz.

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for `"from " + clazz.getSimpleName() + " where ..."`?

Comment: It should work, but I prefer waxwing's answer as using the Criteria API seems nice when constructing this type of query at runtime. Thank you for answering though! (I upvoted it too of course.)

Comment: True, the Criteria API is better for this kind of queries than HQL.